# MVC htaccess block javascript

Tags: .htaccess

Hello i have a htaccess file who should rewrite all to index.php but except js,css,png files, and this htaccess should load js,css,png files but it doesnt loading it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?checkPage=$1&check=$2  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?checkPage=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive. So your second rule has no preceding conditions, so it will naturally rewrite your `.js` files as well.

However, you are also checking that the request is not `/index.html`, but you are rewriting to `index.php`. These should presumably be the same. Although you could probably remove this check altogether by making your regex more specific.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?checkPage=$1&check=$2  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?checkPage=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, both theses conditions could probably be removed by simply making your regex more specific, depending on the format of your URLs (which you've not stated).